# Can I archive an Apple TV App without owning an actual device?

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I have just finished building an Apple TV app, which runs on the simulator fine.

I am now trying to Archive it, and I am getting the following error:

```
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website.
Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
```

Does this mean that I have to have an actual Apple TV connected to my computer before I can Archive this app?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You likely need to select *Generic tvOS Device* as build target and then archive. At least that's how it works for iOS.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth - This does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

As @LinusGeffarth told, you need to select any tvOS device to build.

[image: Example]